# this.userId results in an undefined error

Tags: meteor

I have a `postItem` template which shows an edit and delete button when it is an own post for the logged in user:

```
  <div class="page-actions">
    {{#if ownPost}}
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{pathFor 'postEdit'}}">edit</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger delete" href="#">delete</a>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
```

The `ownPost` helper looks like this:

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
  ownPost: function() {
    return this.userId === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

But `this.userId` returns `undefined`. I guess it has something to do with the `this` context, but I'm not entirely sure what is going wrong here?

Comment: `console.log(this)` inside your helper and let us know the output.

Comment: in your post document, userId field is not there. you have to explicitly store it while creating the post.

Comment: thanks for the ``console.log(this)`` suggestion, because then I noticed ``this`` had 2 collections, and I need to use ``this.visit.userId``

Comment: have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to console.log(this) to check its context, and following that should check that you're a) publishing the data that you want (are you using pub/sub with specified fields or still prototyping with autopublish/insecure etc?).

Lastly I'd check whether you're saving the data correctly to the document in your collection, but obviously only the user collection inherently possesses a userid.

Inside of template helpers like this, the `this` keyword will refer to object that is populating the template.